# Cannot run ad-hoc iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I am trying to run a beta ad-hoc app on my iPhone for the first time (I am not a developer and have no prior experience with this), and I cannot get it to launch. It shows up in iTunes fine, it transfers to my phone fine, but when I tap its icon it appears to launch, then immediately quits back to the home screen. I tried downloading the SDK and adding it through there, and it gave me this error message:

"The Info.plist for application at [redacted].app specifies a CFBundleExecutable of [redacted].app/[app name], which is not executable"

Sorry I can't be more specific, but this app is still under NDA. Anyway, if anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know soon. In case it matters, I am using an iPhone 3GS with 3.1.2 and iTunes 9.02. Thank you!

Comment: This isn'r really a programming question and doesn't belong here. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought this might not be the best place, but I was desperate to try anywhere that looked promising. Anyway, I got my answer, so I won't bother you anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. It was just a permissions error. A simple `chmod +x [AppName]` command in Terminal is all it took to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, so building on your answer, you need to navigate INSIDE the .app package from Terminal and then give the above mentioned command.